# Incremental Math Trouble

Tags: java, math

I've been perplexed about how to write the math for a small game I'm creating. The game is for my own personal journey to learning more about Java and is largely based off of The Monolith, http://monolith.greenpixel.ca/. I've looked at the source code for the game but can't ascertain how the developer does the math.

Here is my code for what I have so far.

```
package DamageDealer;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Take1 {

    int dmg = 0;
    int epoints = 1000;
    int intUnit1 = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Take1();
    }

    public Take1() {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName()); }
                catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace(); }
                catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace(); }
                catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace(); }
                catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace(); }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Button Clicker");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.getContentPane().add(new addComponentsToPane());



                frame.setSize(300, 500);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.setResizable(false);
            }
        });
    }   

    protected class addComponentsToPane extends JPanel {


        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public addComponentsToPane() {
            JPanel appPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();            

            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);

            JLabel EvoPoints = new JLabel();
            EvoPoints.setText("Points: " + String.valueOf(epoints));
            gbc.gridx = 1;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            appPanel.add(EvoPoints, gbc);

            JButton jbtUnit1 = new JButton("Unit 1");
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 1;
            appPanel.add(jbtUnit1, gbc);

            JLabel lblUnit1 = new JLabel();
            lblUnit1.setText(String.valueOf(intUnit1));
            gbc.gridx = 1;
            gbc.gridy = 1;
            appPanel.add(lblUnit1, gbc);

            JButton jbtDamage = new JButton("Damage");                      
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 10;
            appPanel.add(jbtDamage, gbc);

            JLabel DamageOutput = new JLabel();
            DamageOutput.setText(String.valueOf(dmg));
            gbc.gridx = 1;
            gbc.gridy = 10;
            appPanel.add(DamageOutput, gbc);

            add(appPanel, gbc);

            jbtDamage.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    dmg++;
                    DamageOutput.setText(String.valueOf(dmg));
                    if ((dmg % 10) == 0) {
                        epoints++;
                        EvoPoints.setText("Points: " + String.valueOf(epoints));
                    }

                }
            });

            jbtUnit1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (epoints >= 10) {
                        intUnit1++;
                        epoints = epoints - 10;
                        lblUnit1.setText(String.valueOf(intUnit1));
                        EvoPoints.setText("Points: " + String.valueOf(epoints));
                    }
                }
            });
        }          
    }
}
```

Right now, I only have the two buttons, `jbtUnit1` and `jbtDamage`. And their respective action listeners at the bottom.

The math that I have currently only works if the `dmg` value is evenly divisible by ten. At which point (when `dmg` is divisible by 10), the `epoints` value is incremented. However, my `jbtUnit1` is supposed to increment my `dmg` output an additional point for each unit. Therefore, the `(dmg % 10) == 0` won't work because you would surpass values multiple times before reaching an exact `%10`.

Question: how should I do the math? Or better yet: what is the better (or preferred) method for doing this type of math?

Thanks for the help!
Mikey

Comment: Oh, and please disregard the layout. I don't think it's correct. But I'm still teaching myself how to work with layouts.

Comment: So the math only works when dmg % 10 == 0. I'm with you so far. But what do you WANT it to do? Round down (dmg / 10)?

Comment: I want it to increment my `epoints` by one for every 10 points of damage inflicted. But my `jbtUnit1` will increment my damage output by 1 with each unit. Therefore, at some point, say 3 damage output, you'd get 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30. At which one you'd only receive one point but really should have received 3. One at 10, 20, and then 30.

Comment: I'd love to help you more on this but I am not sure I understand exactly what you mean. Maybe we could talk about it more in a chat?

Comment: I think you should just use straight division and not modulus operator. So if a user accumulates 30 points, you do 30/10 = 3. So increment dmg by 3. Whereas with modulus, you do 30%10=0 which gets you into your if statement but you end up only incrementing by 1. Also, if you accumulate say 33 points, you still increment damage by 3 (integer math dictates 33/10=3). And if you care about the remainder, then use modulus (33%10=3).

Comment: @richardsong I don't really care about the remainder. I used the modulo as means of a hard stop. But doing what you suggest, how would that come out? 
Would it be like, `dmg/10=epoints`? ... That might work?!

Comment: you have it backwards, assuming you want to set epoints it would be `epoints+=dmg/10`. This means if your damage is 34, you will add 3 to epoints (`epoints+=34/10 -> epoints+=3). If you need to use modulus to check for certain cases you can still use that in your if statement and inside your if statement do `epoints+=dmg/10;` rather than `epoints++;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing this:

```
dmg++;
DamageOutput.setText(String.valueOf(dmg));
if ((dmg % 10) == 0) {
    epoints++;
    EvoPoints.setText("Points: " + String.valueOf(epoints));
}
```

with this:

```
dmg+= 1+intUnit1; //Deal more damage with more units
DamageOutput.setText(String.valueOf(dmg));
int newEPoints = dmg/10 - spentEPoints;
if(epoints != newEPoints) {
    EvoPoints.setText("Points: " + String.valueOf(newEPoints));
}
epoints = newEPoints;
```

then add a `spentEPoints` field in your main class to keep track of the amount spent and instead of substracting from your epoints counter every time you buy units, you add the spent amount to your `spentEPoints` counter.

Note however that games like these tend to escalate numbers very quickly and your integer type variables will eventually overflow. Take a look a the [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) class which lets you have *almost* infinitely large numbers.

Comment: So, this method would create a local variable that is used to check against the current points to make sure you're not adding points when they shouldn't be?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot an important part of the game mechanic, I will correct the code in a moment.

Comment: This is very close, but not quite. It's incrementing my epoints properly. However, after clicking the `jbtDamage` button again after purchasing a unit, it then gives back epoints. Each time you purchase a unit 1, it costs 10 epoints. So, with each purchase, epoints != newEPoints. which then adjusts the epoints again.

Comment: See my edited answer. I included a spent points counter that makes the logic easier to understand and solves the issue.

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much! I was having so much frustration with this. Weeks of thinking and looking at other code and trying to find examples. I hope this helps out others in the future!! I voted up the answer but due to reputation limitations it won't show yet. But it will!

Comment: @MikeyHarris Please use the checkmark to "accept" an answer if it solved your problem. You can worry about up voting as soon as you get more reputation by posting good questions and answering others

Comment: @cricket_007 Oh, sorry. For some reason, I thought the up voting is what did it. Thanks and done. =]